# Joi.forbidden() equivalent in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, joi

The below schema allows me to have the `optionalField` required if `value` is set to `option1` but if value is set to `option2` then `optionalField` can be set to anything the user desires. Instead, I want the validation to fail if `value` is set to anything other than `option1` and `optionalField` is passed in.

```
const validValues = ['option1', 'option2']

const sampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    value: {
        type: String,
        enum: validValues,
        required: true
    }   

    optionalField: {
        type: Number,
        required: function() { return this.value === 'option1' }
        // validation should fail if this property is passed in when value is anything but option1
    }
})
```

Joi has an excellent way to achieve this using `Joi.forbidden()`:

```
const validValues = ['option1', 'option2']

const schema = Joi.object({
    value: Joi.string().valid(...validValues).required(),
    optionalField: Joi.string().when('value', { is: 'option1', then: Joi.required() otherwise: Joi.forbidden() })
})
```

If I validate with this schema and `optionalField` is passed in to Joi, the validation will fail unless `value` is `option1`.

I am hoping to find a way to achieve the same in Mongoose.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [custom validators](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators) like this:

```js
  optionalField: {
    type: Number,
    required: function() {
      return this.value === "option1";
    },
    validate: {
      validator: function(v) {
        console.log({ v });
        return !(this.value !== "option1" && v.toString());
      },
      message: props =>
        `${props.value} optionalField is forbidden when value is not option1`
    }
  }
```

Sample route:

```js
router.post("/sample", (req, res) => {
  const sample = new Sample(req.body);

  sample
    .save()
    .then(doc => res.send(doc))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
});
```

Input 1:

```
{
    "value": "option2",
    "optionalField": 11
}
```

Result 1: (error)

```
{
    "errors": {
        "optionalField": {
            "message": "11 optionalField is forbidden when value is not option1",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "11 optionalField is forbidden when value is not option1",
                "type": "user defined",
                "path": "optionalField",
                "value": 11
            },
            "kind": "user defined",
            "path": "optionalField",
            "value": 11
        }
    },
    "_message": "Sample validation failed",
    "message": "Sample validation failed: optionalField: 11 optionalField is forbidden when value is not option1",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Input 2:

```
{
    "value": "option2"
}
```

Result 2: (success)

```
{
    "_id": "5e031b473cbc432dfc03fa0e",
    "value": "option2",
    "__v": 0
}
```

Input 3:

```
{
    "value": "option1"
}
```

Result 3: (error)

```
{
    "errors": {
        "optionalField": {
            "message": "Path `optionalField` is required.",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "message": "Path `optionalField` is required.",
                "type": "required",
                "path": "optionalField"
            },
            "kind": "required",
            "path": "optionalField"
        }
    },
    "_message": "Sample validation failed",
    "message": "Sample validation failed: optionalField: Path `optionalField` is required.",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Input 4:

```
{
    "value": "option1",
    "optionalField": 11
}
```

Result 4: (success)

```
{
    "_id": "5e031ba83cbc432dfc03fa10",
    "value": "option1",
    "optionalField": 11,
    "__v": 0
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using something very similar:

`optionalField: {
  type: Number,
  required: function() { return this.value === 'option1' },
  validate(optionalField) {
   if (this.value !== 'option1') {
    if (optionalField) throw new Error() 
   }
  }
}`